# SQL Treatment of Decimal and Float Data Types

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

Why does this

```
weightedValue = CAST(prob*value as FLOAT(53))/CAST(totalValue as FLOAT(53))
```

return the decimal answer in its entirety, but this

```
weightedValue = CAST(prob*value as DECIMAL(38,14))/CAST(totalValue as DECIMAL(38,14))
```

returns the decimal answer truncated at the 6th decimal place?

'Prob' is declared as a DECIMAL(16,14), 'value' is DECIMAL(17,0), 'weightedValue' are all decimal values and assume total value doesn't exceed the exceed the DECIMAL(38,14) specification.

Unless I'm missing something, the DECIMAL(38,14) notation ought to give a value with up to 38 total numbers and up to 14 decimal precision.  Thus, I shouldn't encounter any truncation in the result, no?

Further, I had previously thought that using DECIMAL(,) was always preferable to using FLOAT() based on the imprecision implicit in float arithmetic and associated uncertainty with results--DECIMAL() could be used to do anything FLOAT() could do but not vice versa.  What am I missing and is this, in fact, not the case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is with how SQL Server handles Decimal division (or multiplication).

The formula for the resulting precision is a follows:

```
p1 - s1 + s2 + max(6, s1 + p2 + 1)
```

So, when you have a `DECIMAL(38,14)/DECIMAL(38,14)`, you get a precision of

> 38 - 14 + 14 + max(6, 14 + 38 + 1) = 81

Therefore your result would be a DECIMAL(81,43) which far exceeds the allowed (38,14).  Therefore, SQL Server automatically truncates the answer.

See [blogs.msdn.com](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sqlprogrammability/archive/2006/03/29/564110.aspx) for a more detailed explanation.